# Android libgdx: splash screen not showing immediately after launcher icon pressed

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm programming a libgdx game, but it is not showing splash screen immediately after the game launches. I'm using asset manager to  load resources in the background. does anyone know how this comes?
It only shows a black screen when game launches then after 5-6 seconds when assets loaded in the memory it shows splash screen for a second then he main screen.

Here are my classes.

```
public class SplashScreen implements Screen {

  private SpriteBatch batch;
  private Texture logo;
  private BabyGame game;
  private MyAssetManager myAssetManager;
  public SplashScreen(BabyGame game) {
    this.game = game;
    myAssetManager = new MyAssetManager();
  }
  @Override
  public void show() {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    logo = new Texture("bg.png");
  }
  @Override
  public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.8f, 0.8f, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.begin();
   batch.draw(logo,0,0,Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    batch.end();

    if (myAssetManager.update())
        game.setScreen(new BabyOrange(game));

}
```

Here is Game class

```
 public class BabyGame extends Game
 {
 AdService adService;
 MyAssetManager assetManager;
 public BabyGame(){
    assetManager = new MyAssetManager();
 }
 @Override
 public void create() {
    setScreen(new SplashScreen(this));
 }
}
```

and the asset class

```
public class MyAssetManager {
public  AssetManager manager;
public  MyAssetManager(){
    manager = new AssetManager();
}
public void load(){
    manager.load("background-orange.png",Texture.class);
    manager.load("orange-phone.png",Texture.class);
    manager.load("buttons.txt", TextureAtlas.class);
    manager.load("bgAudio.mp3", Music.class);
    manager.finishLoading();

}
public boolean update(){
    return manager.update();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     You can add Handler() Method in :
     new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
     public void run() {
      startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
       finish();
        }
             }, 1000);
              And also please check the size of the images.
```

Comment: I  only want to show it when assets are loaded in memory and i don't think its a matter of image size because image is showing for a second  after the assets are loaded.